# Capturing data in regex with a combination of double quotes

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

To start- I have done some regex (not an expert by any means) but this is stumping me.

regex flavor is pcre (php)

I am trying to get values out of some fields contained in events in Splunk. Specifically, inbox rule events from exchange.

The catch its that the values are encapsulated in quotes(").  So a "From" field with NO value looks something like: 
 `From="". One with an actual value would look like From=""Smith, John" [SMTP:johnsmith@example.com] or From="Microsoft At Home" or From=""Systems"[[EX:/O=<organization>/OU=******/cn=Recipients/cn=******]".`
The next field in the event is ExceptFrom="".

I have a regex pattern:

```
`(?:\bFrom=(?:")(?:"|(?:))(?P<From_fixed>((.+?))|((.+?)))(?:"))`
```

that kind of works but has to many issues that I have to filter out later on in the process.  Also, when the data looks like From="", it captures the next field of ExceptFrom="".

Can you help me figure out a regex that gets the Value between the inner set of quotes if there are double quotes, the value in between quotes if there are single quotes, and not return a value if there are just a set of double quotes ("").
The last one is a nice-to-have since I can just ignore that later, but it would make the data look better.

These should be captured in named group From_fixed
These are examples of the data I'm working with:

1. From="" ExceptIfFrom="" HasAttachment="False" - Desired result= or ""
2. From="Upcoming Events" ExceptIfFrom="" - Desired result=Upcoming Events
3. From=""Smith, John" [SMTP:johnsmith@example.com] - Desired results=Smith, John
4. From=""Systems"[[EX:/O=/OU=******/cn=Recipients/cn=******]" - Desired results=Systems

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please format your post properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Regex:

```
/(?<=From=\"\"?)(?: |[^"]+)/g
```

It starts by looking back, ensuring that there's 'From="' at start, then it checks whether there's a Space or a quoted string and matches that.
It returns an empty match, if there's a Space after the double quotes, otherwise it returns the value between quotes.
**Edit**:

Try this instead, I forgot about the '`?`' quantifier:

```
\b(?:From=""?(?: |([^"]+)))\b
```

This Regex doesn't use lookback, instead you get the result in `Group 1`.

It starts by matching '`From="`' with one or two quotes, followed by a Space or any number of characters no being a quote, grapping the quoted value in Group 1.

Comment: Thanks! With pcre I had to remove the second"?" or I would get an error: "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width". After re-checking that works partially.  It is not picking up on strings that are contained withing quotes. So it does not pick up on From="Upcoming Events" ExceptIfFrom="" - Desired result=Upcoming Events.  Very helpful so far!